# jQuery - Each 3 a href from each div!

Tags: jquery

I have some div's like

```
<div class="block-wrap">
<a href="#">A</a>
<a href="#">A</a>
<a href="#">A</a>
<a href="#">A</a>
<a href="#">A</a>
<a href="#">A</a>
</div>

<div class="block-wrap">
<a href="#">A</a>
<a href="#">A</a>
<a href="#">A</a>
<a href="#">A</a>
<a href="#">A</a>
<a href="#">A</a>
</div>
```

etc

and a jQuery.

```
$('div.block-wrap a').each(function(index) {
  if ((index+ 1) % 3 == 0)
     $(this).after("<span></span>");
});
```

This ads after 3 *a href* a span, but if I have in a div just 2 *a href*, it will add the span in the next div after one *a href*.
I need this count to be made for each div separately.
Can anybody help?
Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do a separate iteration for each `block-wrap`.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/Q5Bzj/1/

```
$('div.block-wrap').each(function() {
  $(this).children('a').each(function(index) {
     if ((index+ 1) % 3 == 0)
         $(this).after("<span></span>");
   });
});
```

---

If you want each `block-wrap` to end with a `<span>` no matter what, you can do this:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/Q5Bzj/

```
$('div.block-wrap').each(function() {
    $(this).children('a').each(function(index) {
     if (index % 3 == 2)
         $(this).after("<span></span>");
    }).end().children('a:last-child').after("<span></span>");
});
```

Comment: You're quick! +1 for speed, also refining the `a` selector (probably what the OP would want).